# Ошибка в консоли в браузере

Tags: html

Учусь вёрстке. В любой вёрстке в браузерной консоли появляется ошибка "Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received". Она не зависит от языка, только html и css или js json. Что эта за ошибка? Она как-то влияет на код или нет? Её можно исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, ошибку даёт не сайт, а одно из установленных расширений в браузере. Можно попробовать отключать плагины по одному и проверять. Я бы начал с расширения AdobePDF.

Comment: Спасибо, дело было в saveVPN.  Буду отключать при необходимости